# nHibernate join alias projecting some fields

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following query in nHibernate, which works really well.

```
Table1 table1Alias = null;
Table2 table2Alias = null;
Table3 table3Alias = null;
Table4 table4Alias = null;
Table5 table5Alias = null;
Table6 table6Alias = null;

var resultTable = session.QueryOver<Table1>()
               .JoinAlias(x => x.Table2, () => table2Alias, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
               .JoinAlias(() => table2Alias.Table3, () => itemDesctable3AliasriptionAlias, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
               .JoinAlias(() => table2Alias.Table4, () => table4Alias, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
               .JoinAlias(x => x.Table5, () => table5Alias, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
               .JoinAlias(() => table5Alias.Table6, () => table6Alias, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)                                             
               .Where(x => x.Id == inputId)
               .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
               .SingleOrDefault();
```

the problem is, i suspect i'll run into performance issues because
some of the tables have a lot of columns.

So here's the question, let's say I only need 1 field from "Table 5", but
fields from the rest of the table, do i have to do manual projections for all tables? or is there a way to only do manual projection for one table but left the rest as is?

Comment: AFAIK you can't do what you're after. Have you measured the performance to see if selecting more columns makes a difference though?

Comment: Ok - i just needed to know if it's possible - thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Is this query just an example, or are you actually not selecting anything or using `WHERE` on the joined tables? If not, you could just remove the `JOIN`s.

Comment: No - it's not an example, it's a real code with the entity names removed. I was trying to load an entity and deep load several of the sub collections.

Comment: I would recommend doing a projection or loading the properties/entities you want one by one, using Future<> to get 1 call to the db. But that wasn't what you wanted :). Mabye LazyProperties could help? http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties